# Making the FAQ more precise.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, challenges, clarification

After asking [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/what-is-a-good-way-to-deal-with-tasks-that-requires-arrays-using-haskell) question, I got a downvote promptly. A user told me in the comments, that this page is for programming challenges and not for questions about how to be better in such challenges. I showed the user [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) question about tips for golfing in Python and about many on-topic questions about such things during the definition phase.

I kindly request the admins of this site to add a small paragraph in the FAQ page, that questions about tips for better gofing etc. are welcome on this page, or a paragraph, that states the opposite, if such questions aren't welcome here. (But where to post such a question else?)

Comment: I've also posted to chat on the matter. My feeling is that these posts are probably allow, but probably should be CW. However, I won't invoke any moderator superpower until I get some feedback.

Comment: Related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/27/78

Comment: I opened a [question at SO-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84788/clarification-about-place-for-a-question) about this issue.

Comment: Frankly I don't see this as an issue for the mother meta. Such a question would be OK on SO, but the issue is *"Does it belong on codgolf.se?"*, which is for the users of codegolf.se to answer. Several codegolf mods have looked at it, and there is not groundswell from the user base suggesting it should be closed, so it will probably stay open.

Comment: A side comment: have patience, things move slowly here. We have a low traffic site with relatively few users and comments and opinions accumulate at a rate than reflects this.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm the philistine in question, I might as well throw the first... Uh... Nevermind, that metaphor wasn't going anywhere.

> But where to post such a question else?

Stackoverflow... As CW if it isn't specific enough. Whatever the original reason was for moving code golf to a separate SE, Stackoverflow is still fair game for most coding questions so I don't see why to put them somewhere else.

Comment: I guess, in SO, they would migrate this question to codegolf.